# calculate the average repair time from multiple start and end dates in mysql database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that has two columns, one called exstdate which is the start date and exrdate which is the end date and is a lot of records in the table and I want to be find the average repair time in days of all the records dates and output it.

I came up with a SQL query but not 100% sure, it outputs the result as 2.4 so might be correct but 100% sure if it's the correct query

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(DATEDIFF( exrdate, exstdate )), 1) AS avg_repair_time FROM repairs
```

Can anyone tell me if that is the correct query please to output the average repair time in days from all the records start and end date columns, the type for the dates columns in the database table is using date

Comment: Looks OK I guess? Have you done anything to test the result? Should only take a sample table with about five rows to confirm the result.

Comment: I only put the query into phpmyadmin, I could add a LIMIT of 5 onto the query to see if get the correct result still. I've not tested it in a php page yet as was seeing if can get the SQL query correct first

Comment: I don't think the query is correct as added LIMIT onto the end and still getting 2.4 as the result. The amended query looks like this: SELECT ROUND(AVG(DATEDIFF( exrdate, exstdate )), 1) AS avg_repair_time FROM repairs LIMIT 5

Comment: Just cook up a table with five rows and then you can adjust the values to test your query.

Comment: I copied the db table and only got five rows of records and changed dates and did the query and got 0.2 so changed dates to be different ones and made them longer date gap between start date and end date and ran the query again and got 9.4 so does look like the SQL query is correct, just need to code in the php now but main thing is got the query correct. Thank you Jerry for your help, if get bit stuck on the php, I'll create a new thread/post

Comment: All sorted and got it working with the php code